# Adding installed libraries via pip with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to package a python project, how do I add the installed libraries via pip into the executable?
Added the libraries to be included and if necessary, installed in the requirements.txt file.
Thank you in advance.

I tried venv and path addition but nothing.

Comment: can you provide a [repro]

Comment: AFAICS `pyinstaller yourfile.py` should create the spec file, see [the manual](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html)